# Upload File Ext Js 2.2

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, extjs2

I have the following code to upload the file but I cannot get the file at the php someone knows explain why ?

EXT JS

```
items:
 [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: "Anexo",
    id: 'anexohelp',
    name: 'anexohelp',
    inputType:'file',
 }]
```

PHP

```
$file     = $_FILES['anexohelp'];
$filename = $file['name'];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get file using this `$_FILES["file_name_here"]` and you will get here all documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

and example

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
```

```
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image" />
     <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
```